# Qt 5 applications crashing

Tags: windows, qt

I'm new to Qt and installed the SDK version 5.0.1 with MinGW for windows today.

I have the same problem with both the skeleton code generated by the New Project wizard (for Qt widget projects) and all the included sample applications: The code compiles fine but on execution (from within Qt Creator) it crashes with return code -1073741511.

When I try to debug the application it gives me the error "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.". I tried to set a breakpoint at the first line of the main function but it doesn't even reach that point.

My first thought was that it might be missing some of the Qt libraries but the environment PATH variable set in the project configuration in Qt Creator points to the correct directory.

The strange thing is that I also installed the same version on my laptop where everything works fine. However, I'm not aware of any major differences between my working PC and my laptop. Both are running the 64-bit version of Windows 8.

Comment: Do the sample programs installed with the SDK run fine?